# macOS Catalina - postgreSQL - sysctl.conf still relevant?

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I had the following settings in /etc/sysctl.conf before Catalina:

```
# PostgreSQL Config for the MAC
kern.sysv.shmmax=2147483648
kern.sysv.shmall=524288
kern.sysv.shmmin=1
kern.sysv.shmmni=32
kern.sysv.shmseg=8
kern.maxprocperuid=1024
kern.maxproc=2048
```

The Catalina install moved this file to the /Users/Shared folder as /etc is now considered private to macOS.

Are these settings still relevant for Catalina, and if so, where do they need to go?

Thx.

Comment: Are you planning to run scalability tests or production workloads on your Mac? If not, you might as well just leave kernel parameters alone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the shared memory parameters any more, because PostgreSQL has been using POSIX shared memory for a while now.

Making sure that the PostgreSQL user can have enough open files is a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I put the file back (at `/etc/sysctl.conf`) and it worked just like before (at least for setting `kern.maxvnodes`).